# jQuery/CSS Transition: Animate between three variable heights, 1 being auto

Tags: jquery, css, height, css-transitions

Based on information I've found here on Stack I've done the following to animate heights of my divs from a set height to an auto height and back.

```
$('.parent').each(function(){
    $(this).data('height',$(this).css('height'));
    $(this).css('height','20px');
});
$('.parent').click(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    if ($(this).css('height') == '20px') {
        $(this).css({
            height: $(this).data('height'),
            cursor: 'auto'
        });
        $(this).children('.closeButton').fadeIn();
    }
});
$('.closeButton').click(function(){
    var el = $(this).parent();
    var button = $(this);
    el.css('height','0');
    setTimeout(function(){
        el.css({
            height: '20px',
            cursor: 'pointer'
        });
        button.fadeOut();
    },150);
});
$('.makeBigger').click(function(){
   html = 'TONS OF CONTENT MAKES ME BIGGER<br/>TONS OF CONTENT MAKES ME BIGGER<br/>TONS OF CONTENT MAKES ME BIGGER<br/>';
   $('#bigger').append(html);
   $('#bigger').css('height','auto');
});
```

The HTML for the elements is essnetially:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="closeButton">close</div>
    CONTENT
</div>

<div class="parent" id="bigger">
    <div class="closeButton">close</div>
    CONTENT
    <div class="makeBigger">EVEN BIGGER</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
   margin: 30px;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
}
.closeButton {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3uFaq/

This works just fine. However one of my divs contains some form fields that a user can interact with and in turn appends more data to that div. How can I further animate that div to also animate larger? I've tried extensively playing with max-min height and stuff and haven't found the right combination of script to do so.